# Issue with MDS data when viewed in Excel addin after connecting to MDS Model

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, master-data-services

In MDS 2012, while exploring for a entity, I can see the data in Client and Product column are properly assigned as Code and Code {Name} as seen below:

[image]

but while connecting to the MDS model via Excel addin I am not able to see the Product column with Code and Code {Name} data which I can see for Client column in Excel sheet as Code and Code {Name} data. Please see below:

[image]

I have verified the settings of Product with the Client attributes in the MDS. but couldn't see any issue with it.

Can anyone help me with this or anyone has come across this issue before?